# Order after rollup - oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, group-by

I am using rollup() function in group by expression to show the result query,
but my output like this:

```
Year    Month        AmountOfMoney
====    =====        =============
1998    March        130.00
1998    April        450.00    
1988    -            580.00
1999    January      120.00
1999    April        550.00
1999    -            670.00
-       -            1250.00
```

how to make it order by total, then years, then (year,month)

```
Year    Month        AmountOfMoney
====    =====        =============
-       -            1250.00 
1988    -            580.00
1999    -            670.00
1998    March        130.00
1998    April        450.00    
1999    January      120.00
1999    April        550.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a ORACLE user but I've found an interesting article about it:

[**Oracle SQL GROUP BY – The Complete Guide**](https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-group-by/)

Scrolling down till the **GROUPING Function** you'll find and example on how use GROUP BY with ROLLUP:

<sub>Quoted from the article</sub>

> There are several SQL functions related to grouping that can help you
>   identify and work with groups.
>
> Earlier in our examples, we noticed that subtotals had values of NULL
>   for the columns that weren’t being considered in the group.
>
> How can we tell which values are subtotals and which values are NULL
>   because of the underlying data?
>
> This is what the GROUPING function can help with.
>
> The GROUPING function takes a single column as a parameter. The output
>   is either 1 or 0:
>
> It returns 1 if the column is being used as part of a subtotal and is
>   showing NULL. It returns 0 if the underlying value is NULL or any
>   other value.
>
> **You can also order by these columns, to have the subtotals at the**
>   **start or the end, instead of in the middle of the results.**

According to this you could use the next syntax to produce the expected result:

```
SELECT
    Year,
    Month,
    SUM(Amount) as AmoutOfMone
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY ROLLUP (Year, Month)
ORDER BY
    GROUPING(Year) DESC,
    GROUPING(Month) DESC,
    Year ASC,
    Month ASC;
```

Due this question has a previous question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/225628/110455), I've used my fiddle to add this new information and it works properly.

```
/* aggregated sales by year-month */
SELECT
    T.CALENDAR_YEAR AS Year,
    T.CALENDAR_MONTH_DESC AS Month,
    SUM(S.AMOUNT_SOLD) AS AmountOfMoney
FROM
    SALES S
JOIN
    TIMES T
    ON T.TIME_ID = S.TIME_ID
WHERE S.PROD_ID = 1
GROUP BY ROLLUP (T.CALENDAR_YEAR, T.CALENDAR_MONTH_DESC)
ORDER BY GROUPING (T.CALENDAR_YEAR) DESC, 
         GROUPING (T.CALENDAR_MONTH_DESC) DESC, 
         CALENDAR_YEAR ASC,
         CALENDAR_MONTH_DESC ASC;
```

```
YEAR | MONTH | AMOUNTOFMONEY
---: | ----: | ------------:
null |  null |           450
2018 |  null |           450
2018 |     1 |           100
2018 |     2 |           200
2018 |     3 |           150
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6219eb401019056ee086772a50c5af75)*